# Adverts on a mercantile site: good or bad?

Tags: advertising, ecommerce, google-adsense

Is it generally considered a good or bad idea to put GoogleAds or the like on a web site that is selling items online? In other words, should one run the risk of having the competition appear in these ads or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your marginal revenue is less than the amount earned on a click, probably not... but, if that were the case, there doesn't seem to be much sense in running a shop to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that the entire reason for having a mercantile site would be to convert browsers into buyers.  Allowing them the possibility of clicking away from your site in return for a small bit of ad revenue seems counter productive.